# JavaFX mouse click event for Labels

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, pane

I am trying to build a simple planner app using JavaFX. My current goal is to be able to:

1. click on a panel of the calendar (already implemented)
2. type in a task, hit enter and have it show up as a Label (already implemented)
3. click on the currently placed labels and remove them from the calendar. (issue)

Step 3 is where I am having most trouble. I am confident that I am setting up my mouse event for the label correctly but when I click on one of the labels it runs the mouse event for the panel. I need a way to override the pane's mouse event so I can use the labels mouse event, but I'm not too sure how to go about that. Any feedback would be great!

```
this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> 
    {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        this.getChildren().add(field);

        //sets field as a label
         field.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
                    KeyCode k = key.getCode();
                    if ((k.equals(KeyCode.ENTER))) {
                        Label lab = new Label(field.getText());
                        getChildren().add(lab);
                        getChildren().remove(field);
                    }
                }
            });

         //removes textfield and label
         field.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                KeyCode kc = ke.getCode();
                if ((kc.equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE))) {
                    getChildren().remove(field);
                }
            }
        });      
    }); 
    if(lab != null)
    {
        lab.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00FF00;");
            }
          });
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with runnable code.

Comment: @MonopoleMagnet yes of course, the project spans across a few classes, but I can give an example of the mouse event handling. I know this isn't really reproducible, so I apologize. I can't really reproduce the issue without  all of the code :/

Comment: Which one is the mouse event handler in question? Currently there's only one for setting the background color for some node never mentioned anywhere else. BTW: note that you're replacing the first key event handler instead of combining both...

Comment: _click on the currently placed labels and remove them from the calendar_ why not use buttons instead of labels ?

Comment: _I can't really reproduce the issue without all of the code_ try harder - stripping it down until only the error remains is the only way to find it :)

Comment: You aren't consuming the event (i.e. `e.consume()`). If the event is not consumed it will continue to bubble up the scene graph which means your label's container's mouse-event handler will also be invoked. Many of the skin implementations for controls auto-consume mouse events, but `Label`'s skin is not one of them.

Comment: @kleopatra sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, but there wasn't actually an error happening. I just had an issue with stacking my mouse events where the panes event would override the labels event. It seems that "Slaw" had the right solution to this issue though.

Comment: @Slaw thank you! that makes a lot more sense, I will look into consume and see if it works!